# Python string comparisons?

Tags: python, string, comparison, equality

I cannot get a string comparison to work in Python, now I have looked at this, and tried so many times, hit my head so many times it's crazy, I explain:

I have a function that returns a list of tuples called: sites

```
('http://somewebsite.com', 'somewebsite')
('http://somewebsite2.com', 'somewebsite2')
('http://somewebsite3.com', 'somewebsite3')
```

Now knowing the title of a website, for this example: somewebsite2
I use a for loop:

```
for url, name in sites:
    if name == title:
       screamandshout()
```

I can not get a match to occur no matter how i try.

```
        log.log('title type= %s and value= %s' % (str(type(title)), title))
        log.log('name type= %s and value= %s' % (str(type(name)), name))
        log.log(str(str(name) == title))
        log.log(str(name == str(title)))
        log.log(str(str(name) == str(title)))
        log.log(str(name] is title))
```

I have ensured the types and values, i have tried reverse comparison, I am absolutely gobsmacked to have lost several hours of my life on this. I there something so simple I am not understanding about puython, because I have followed everything I can..

What I am trying to do is match the name to the title and return the website.

this is a runnable example however it works, this is why i am so confused lol

```
sites = [
('http://somewebsite.com', 'somewebsite'),
('http://somewebsite2.com', 'somewebsite2'),
('http://somewebsite3.com', 'somewebsite3')
]
print str(type(sites))

title = 'somewebsite2'

for site in sites:
    print str(type(site))

for url, name in sites:
    if name == title:
       print 'MATCH!'
```

This outputs the following

```
<type 'list'>
 <type 'tuple'>
 <type 'tuple'>
 <type 'tuple'>
MATCH!
```

Oh, i am using python 2.7

Comment: Have you tried adding an `else: print(name, title)`?

Comment: Please reduce your program to the smallest possible **complete** program that others will be able to run. Please copy-paste that **entire** program into your question. For more information, see [mcve] from the [ask] section of the [help].

Comment: `"apple" == "apple"` ....

Comment: normally `==` tests the equality between strings in Python. Are you sure your strings are equal?

Comment: You recent update hard codes `title` and unsurprisingly your code now works. How is `title` being set in your real code?

Comment: I am a little confused about your question. Are you trying to check if, let's say `'somewebsite2'` is  in `'http://somewebsite2.com'` in all the `tuples` in your list?

Comment: @mhawk It is being pulled from a node in an xml tree, i have checked its a string and the value is as expected.

Comment: @RonAppleton: have you tried printing `title` as described in my answer, i.e. using `%r` instead of `%s`?

Comment: How is a non-representative example supposed to allow others to reproduce and solve the issue?

Comment: A minimal example is not what would have been represented Tigerhawk, the code I am using is huge. mhawke has however helped me suss this, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values of `name` and `title` must be different.

Try printing them out - possibly `title` contains some trailing whitespace (space, tab, newline, etc.) that is not revealed by your log statements. Change your log statement to use the `%r` format for the variable's value like this:

```
log.log('title type= %s and value= %r' % (str(type(title)), title))
log.log('name type= %s and value= %r' % (str(type(name)), name))
```

That should make any difference apparent.

On a related note why are you using a list of tuples and then iterating over them? It seems that a dictionary would be a better data structure because it allows efficient lookup by using the name/title as a key:

```
if title in sites:
    screamandshout()
```

If you can't modify the function to return a dictionary, and you need to perform multiple lookups on the same data, you can transform its return value into a dictionary:

```
sites = {name:url for url, name in f()}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, indeed after using %r instead it has revealed that the function returning values from the xml tree node is indeed adding a trailing whitespace. I guesss this is how you learn. Thank you very much. Also for the advice on the dictionary, i will use this. The list is populated by a session request: livePage = session.get(portal_add + '/client_area/live.php', headers=headers)
        pages = re.compile("\{link:\'(.*?)\'.*\'(.*?)\'}", re.VERBOSE).findall(livePage.content)
        return pages

Comment: @RonAppleton: no problem. To fix it you can `strip()` the `title` when it's retrieved from the xml node, or when performing the comparison: `if name == title.strip()`. I still think that you are better off with a dictionary.

Comment: thanks I completely agree, i will be using the dictionary example you have given, thanks again.

Comment: if using the dict to return the url when matching the title to the name, how would i go about that please? Or rather if I find the title in sites, return the appropriate url?

Comment: I take it, it should be if title in sites: return sites[title]

Comment: Wahey, my brain isnt completely useless, thanks @mhawke you are a god, thank you